# How to read a table from MySQL work bench in colab

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, google-colaboratory, pymysql

I have referred various articles in stackoverflow and external sources but somehow unable to get answer for this. I want to read a table from MySQL workbench database into a dataframe in colab.

**1st Method**

In this method, first line of code is successfully executed.
Note: I have hidden database, table and password name for security reasons.

Source -

```
USER = 'root'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
DATABASE = 'DATABASE'
TABLE = 'TABLE'
 
connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://root:PASSWORD/DATABASE' 
 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
```

**I am getting error for second line of code. Is it because my password ends with @786 or some other reasons.**

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

**OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '786@3306' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)") (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
**

**2nd Method**

In this method, first line of code is successfully executed.
Note: I have hidden database, table and password name for security reasons.

```
connection_string = 'mysql+pymysql://root:PASSWORD@3306/DATABASE'
connect_args = {'ssl': {'ca': '/content/rds-ca-2015-root.pem'}}

db = create_engine(connection_string, connect_args=connect_args)
```

I am getting error for second line of code.

```
query = """SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE"""

events_df = pd.read_sql(query, con=db)
```

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory **

**My Queries:**
***1)   Why I am getting error for 2nd line of code in both methods?
2)  Is there any workaround or alternative approach / codes where I can successfully connect colab with MySQL database and read table?***

Comment: `connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://root:PASSWORD/DATABASE'` should probably be: `connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://root:{PASSWORD}/{DATABASE}'`

Comment: @BeRT2me I am getting below error when I have edited the code.
NameError: name 'DATABSE' is not defined

Comment: looks like you misspelled `DATABASE` later in your code `NameError: name 'DATABSE' is not defined`

Comment: @bherbruck DATABASE is just representational not actual. I  have hidden name for security  purpose.

Comment: do you have the host (server ip/hostname) in your connection string?

Comment: @bherbruck, I have installed mysql workbench on laptop. I am working on colab and trying to connect MySQL with colab.  So my localhost is 3306.

Comment: Colab is running in the cloud and does not have access to your local machine (that's good for security) so you will not be able to connect. Try hosting a cloud MySQL database somewhere or using a local colab instance https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html